# ModuleNotFoundError when python runs as a job in SQL Server Agent

Tags: python, sql-server

### What I want to do

I have a python script that imports some modules like `pyodbc`, and I'm trying to run the script as a job in SQL Server Agent.

### Background

- The SQL Server is on a different server
- I've connected to the server with my user account (not the user account that runs the SQL agent job: let's say it's `SQLUser`) and installed `pyodbc` on the server (used `pip install pyodbc --user`)
- I've checked `pip list`, `pip3 list`, `pip3.7 list` and `pyodbc` is listed in all in the server
- The script runs fine when I run the script in the server from the command prompt

### problem

When I run the job, it gives me the following error message:

```
Executed as user: DOMAIN\SQLUser. Traceback (most recent call last): File "PathToScript\script.py". line 1, in <module> import pyodbc ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'.
```

How can I run this script with SQL Server Agent or what else can I do to find the cause of this issue?

Comment: SQL Agent runs under (usually) a service account; did you ensure the python path is in that users environment variable?

Comment: @DaveCullum The path is in the server's System variables, but is it that it has to be set in the service account's user variables as well?

Comment: That I do not know.  Things with SQL Agent don't always behave exactly as they would if you were logged on the console with the service account.  Some things don't get fully loaded from the Windows Registry unless there's an active console session, such as SSH keys -- they actually load off the "default' user instead (HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Environment).  We have a similar issue using putty, we have to copy the ssh keys into the default hive for SQL Agent to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't run the script when I run it via SQL Server Agent job because the SQL Server service account doesn't have the module installed, and nobody knows the password for the user.

So, I ran the following code as a SQL Agent job, and I was able to install the module directly for the service account.

```
subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m' 'pip', 'install', 'pyodbc', '--user'])
```